# lotion.js : error in application that counts number of transactions occured so far (TypeError : app.listen is not a function)

Tags: node.js, tendermint, lotionjs

```
let app = require('lotion')({
  initialState: { count: 0 }
})

app.use((state, tx) => {
  state.count++
})

app.listen(3000)
```

On running this code (which I found on the lotion js official website), I am getting this error

```
/home/kashika/node_modules/supercop.js/lib.js:97
  throw ex;
  ^

TypeError: app.listen is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kashika/prog.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:204:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:625:3
```

Answer (score 0):

As Lotion owner said:

> Also, I removed the dependency that was breaking your install on Node
>   11, it should work on either version now (though you may still see
>   some weird warnings on 11, I'd recommend using 10).

**Solution:**

Remove `node_modules` directory and try to install again latest version of `lotion`

create `app.js` and replace:

```
let lotion = require('lotion')

let app = lotion({
    initialState: {
        count: 0
    }
})

function transactionHandler(state, transaction) {
    if (state.count === transaction.nonce) {
        state.count++
    }
}

app.use(transactionHandler)

app.start().then(appInfo => console.log(appInfo.GCI))
```

then run `node app.js` will solve